# Execute specific function in Bash/Shell Script from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, bash, function, shell

I am currently executing a script called `cert-check-script.sh` in my NodeJS `index.js` file using:

```
exec('sh cert-check-script.sh');
```

Is there a way to call a specific function in this script rather than executing the entire thing?

Comment: What's wrong with copying the specific function out of the script and `exec`ing it?

Comment: I was a bit reluctant to separate it into different scripts but it seems the only way, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up just extracting the function code into a separate script and calling `exec` on that.